# Is there a way to mix angular class directive with Boolean and ternary expression?

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I'm trying to write a mix of ternary and Boolean expression in the angular class (ng-class) directive. but I can't find the right syntax to make it work, or find a decent example on the web.

I know that in angular class directive we can write a ternary expression such as the following.

```
<... ng-class="isAdmin ? 'enabled' : 'disabled'" ...>
```

And a Boolean expression such as.

```
<... ng-class="{visible:isPowerUser}" ...>
```

But is there a way to mix them like this?

```
<... ng-class="{visible:isPowerUser} & (isAdmin ? 'enabled' : 'disabled')" ...>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
ng-class="{visible: isPowerUser, enabled: isAdmin, disabled: !isAdmin}"
```

- if the `isAdmin` is `true`, the class **enabled** will be assigned
- else `!isAdmin` (is `false`), the **disabled** class will be assigned

The visible will be also assigned if the `isPowerUser` is true. *More details [ngClass](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass)*

Other options could be like this:

```
ng-class="{visible: isPowerUser && isAdmin}"
```

which will assign `visible` class only if both parts are true

Comment: I know that I could do something like you described. but you are duplicating the isAdmin usage.

So I understand there is no way to mix the boolean and ternary expressions.

Comment: I would take it from another perspective: 1) View perspective - the passed object to `ng-class` is a detailed setting. It contains as many css-class names as we would like to assign. Then we set the expressions, which are managing selection for each of them, but independently on the others. This is the View configuration. 2) model configuration - If we would like to have more complex evaluation of the **isInSomeRole** we can apply that logic in the conntroller and assign it to the Model ($scope). We can test it.. and from the View perspective we are doing the same as in point 1)

Answer (score 0):

You could separate the functionality if its only visible you are worried about for the isPowerUser:

```
ng-if="isPowerUser" ng-class="{true:'enabled', false:'disabled'}[isAdmin]"
```